# consequence of Integral limits same like integrating variable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am thinking about an intuitive explanantion (e.g. suitable for people not having insights in higher mathematics) for what would happen if the limits of the integral were really the same as the integrating variable (not just a writing error or bad notation style):

Look at this thing: $g(x):= \int_{0}^x f(x)\mathrm{d}x$. Some people might say this is wrong since the limits of the integral shouldn't correspond to the integrating variable.
But can 't we say that $g(x)$ with this definition is $0$ for every concrete $x$? E.g.
$g(1)=\int_0^1 f(1) \mathrm d1 = 0$ since $\mathrm d 1= 0$.
This is because in general
$$\mathrm d \ \text{constant}=0$$ because $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \text{constant} = 0 \Rightarrow \mathrm d\ \text{constant} = 0\cdot t = 0$$

$\Rightarrow g(x)= 0$ for every concrete $x$.

Does this make sense to explain why we have to be careful about notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are misinterpreting $\int_0^x f(x)dx.$

The variable $x$ in the **integrand** is a dummy variable that has absolutely no relation to the $x$ that occurs as one of the limits of integration.  This means that

$$\int_0^x f(x)dx = \int_0^x f(t)dt.$$

In fact, there are two reasons why the first expression above can be construed as **bad** or misleading or invalid.

1. In your formulation, attempting to relate the $x$ variable that occurs in the limit of integration to the $x$ variable that occurs as a dummy variable in the integrand is wrong.  Therefore, a case can be made that your formulation is **invalid** because you are **overloading** (or overusing) the $x$ variable.
2. Even ignoring whether your formulation is invalid, it is certainly confusing because it *masks* that the $x$ variable that occurs in the integrand is a dummy variable.